# VBA or Excel formulas to concatentate columnar data in Excel to linear comma separated data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am decomposing an Excel worksheet that made cumbersome use of field merges to organize data. Instead of adding linear fields to each record, the data was organized vertically. Un-merging the fields results in a column of text data with many orphaned values that need to be concatenated into a field in the parent record.  I have added the identifier "NOTE:" at the beginning of the text string of the first field in the record.  I would like to use a function that searches the column for the string "NOTE:", increments the search down the list concatenating the orphan text strings until it reaches the next "NOTE: value, where it will repeat the process for the next group of text strings.

I would normally use simple concatentation, but there are 7500 records and 27k notes entries.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a formula it will require a subscription Office 365 Excel:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,4) = "NOTE",TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,B2:INDEX(B3:$B$104000,IFERROR(MATCH("NOTE*",B3:$B$104000,0)-1,MATCH("ZZZ",B3:$B$104000)))),"")
```

---

If you do not have a Subscription to Office 365 Excel, then add this UDF to a module attached to the workbook and use the formula above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great!  Why the stipulation for **Office 365 Excel**?  Will a full installation of Excel 2013 work?

Comment: maybe, TextJoin was introduce Feb 2016 and is available to Office 365 users.  It may have been added as an addon to Excel 2013.  If not just add the code to a module, it mimics the TextJoin that is native in the newest version of excel.  Then you can use it with the formula I suggested.

Comment: I've added the UDF and the formula, adjusted the cell references, but the formula returns a #NAME? error.  Do I have to register the UDF in some way other than saving it in the VBA module?

Comment: Di you put the code in a module?  It cannot go in the worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code.  You must add a module and put the code in that.  The module must be attached to your workbook.

Comment: Well done, sir!  I started with a new workbook and made certain to clean out all of the other UDFs not in use and it worked as advertised.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: @OldGuy please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Regrets my Friend.  New to this process and forum. Cheers.